# Write string over multiple line in X++

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I have  a string and I want to write it over multiple line, hover I don't want to write it the below way since it would be tedious

```
val = " lines 1 "
     + " lines +
     ....
```

any idea?

Comment: Go through the example in below page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577258.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
str tmp =
@"123
456
789";
```

**Note** the text is aligned all the way to the edge of the editor, otherwise those indentations/spaces will be included in the string.

If that not what you looking for, then maybe `TextBuffer` class will be suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Try with a backslash at the end of the line like this

```
str tmp;
;

tmp = "123\
       456\
       789";
```

Note: The leading spaces in the lines are part of the string, so the result is not 
 `"123456789"` but `"123           456           789"`